# JBPM 5.4 process variables

Tags: drools, jbpm, drools-guvnor

I am new to Jbpm 5.4. I want to set a process variable after completing one Human task. I know we can add process variables at start up using a map. Can any one tell me how set process variable in the middle of the process please???

Answer (score 0):

Result mapping & data associations. Like any other type of task.

See 
https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.human-tasks.html#d0e4970

> Result mapping: Allows copying the value of result parameters of the
>   human task to a process variable. Upon completion of the human task,
>   the values will be copied. A human task has a result variable "Result"
>   that contains the data returned by the human actor. The variable
>   "ActorId" contains the id of the actor that actually executed the
>   task.

also
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/test/resources/BPMN2-DataOutputAssociations.bpmn2
for an example